# how to set a current time in picker view Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with set a current time on my pickerView object.
I have 3 component in it, one for hour, one for minute and last one for second.

I get a current time like this:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
```

I tried to set a current time using:

```
[picker setDate:now]
```

where `picker` is a declaration my PickerView object.

I'll be glad to get a help with set current time on it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is picker instance or subclass of UIDatePicker ?

Comment: picker is declarated in .h file: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker; // I want to set on it current date.

Comment: Try nsdateformater to format your date now to your 3 components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setDate method you are looking for is in [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDatePicker) class.

Note that

> UIDatePicker does not inherit from UIPickerView, but it manages a custom picker-view object as a subview.